# how to play video in application (getting the link in Rest Api) using retrofit in android studio

Tags: android, video, video-streaming, retrofit, retrofit2

I am getting a link to play a video (in my Rest API) in the android application... I am using retrofit to handle my rest api's .... and I am not sure how to use the link for video in my android application ...  can anyone help me how I can play video using retrofit ... thanks :)

```
video_url   :   https://www.youtube.com/embed/0aNNYEUARAk
```

like this, I am getting the URL in JSON response. I want to play this video in an activity with my own controllers.

Comment: you can use https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer for play video from server. If you have youtube video than use youtube video player. https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/

Comment: currently i am having a youtube video .... but its not compulsory that all the timei am getting a youtube video .... video could be from daily motion or any other site .... what should i do now

Comment: please refer SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29607104/how-to-play-youtube-video-in-exoplayer-in-android